# SMSC911x driver locks up on Windows CE device

Tags: networking, embedded, windows-ce, device-driver

I am struggling with a Windows CE device that locks up occasionally when the network cable is unplugged. It is running Windows CE 5.0 and the NIC driver is SMSC911x. It is running version 1.01, and I am unsure where to look for source updates for this driver. Does anybody know where to find an update for this driver and/or have any experience with the driver not behaving on network disconnect with a similar device? Extensive Googling reveals lots of Linux drivers, but not much on the CE front.

Regards,

Freddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a download for CE 5.0 and 6.0 on SMSC's site [at the bottom of the page here](http://www.smsc.com/Products/Ethernet_and_Embedded_Networking/Ethernet_Controllers/LAN9218/Download). It's on the LAN9218 page, but the driver is for "LAN91xx/LAN92xx/LAN9311/LAN9312" so it should apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, I've got the source code for the updated library now and I will be testing it tomorrow.